# Firebug: How can I inspect an element I can't click on?

Tags: dom, hover, firebug, mouseover, inspect

I'm trying to use Firebug to inspect a page element that appears when I hover over a photo.

Problem is, the element's position is dynamically offset from the mouse position, so it's impossible for me to right-click on it to get the "Inspect Element" option.

I had hoped that the onhover element would be inserted into the DOM in a sensible place, but so far, I haven't been able to find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note: I don't know the element's ID, class, etc -- that's what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an ideal solution, but you could investigate the onhover code to find out more information about the element that's being created.  That info might allow you to find it in Firebug's DOM viewer.

Comment: I ended up just poring over the code in the DOM viewer to find the out-of-reach element, but I'll use this suggestion in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you know *where* in the DOM the new element will be created (quite often those elements are created as children of the `body` element) you can set up a breakpoint for when it is created.

Let's assume that the element will be created as a child of the `body` element. You will be able to inspect the element if you follow these steps:

1. Load the page
2. activate FireBug's HTML panel
3. Locate the `body` element
4. Right-click on the `body` element and choose `Break on Child Addition or Removal` from the popup menu
5. Go hover over your photo to trigger the wanted element's creation

Script execution should then break as soon as the element is created. At that point you will have all the time you need to inspect that dynamically created element, even in the HTML panel.

Comment: Wow, this is ingenious, thanks. I just checked and it seems Chrome has this functionality too. This will come in very handy indeed. :)

Comment: BTW this solution is great, but the page im trying to examine has many hundreds of mutations on the body element, and the event im looking to trap is hard to predict when its going to happen, what i would really like is a way to freeze the dom with a keyboard shortcut or bookmarklet when the element pops up, so i could then inspect the frozen transitory popup element. the element i want to examine pops up at random.

Answer (score 0):

Can you search for the element using the search bar at the top of the firebug window?

Answer (score -1):

You can use CTRL+F to find it in the code view.